# Return a zip (or any file) from the server on the client browser (REST)

Tags: java, angular, rest, download, zip

So I am using Java for my Server and Angular for the Client. I am currently working on a feature where you can select multiple files from a table and when you press on download, it generates a zip file and downloads it to your browser. As of right now, the server now creates the zip file and I can access it in the server files. All that is left to do is to make it download on the client's browser. (the zip file is deleted after the client downloads it)

After doing some research, I found out that you can use a fileOutputStream to do this. I also saw some tools like retrofit... I am using REST and this is what my code looks like. How would I achieve my goal as simply as possible?

**Angular**

```
  httpGetDownloadZip(target: string[]): Observable<ServerAnswer> {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('target', String(target)).set('numberOfFiles', String(target.length));
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('token', this.tokenService.getStorageToken());
    const options = {
      headers,
      params,
    };
    return this.http
      .get<ServerAnswer>(this.BASE_URL + '/files/downloadZip', options)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<ServerAnswer>('httpGetZip')));
  }
```

**Java zipping method**

```
    public void getDownloadZip(String[] files, String folderName) throws IOException {
        [...] // The method is huge but basically I generate a folder called "Download/" in the server

        // Zipping the "Download/" folder
        ZipUtil.pack(new File("Download"), new File("selected-files.zip"));

        // what do I return ???
        return;
    }
```

**Java context**

```
            server.createContext("/files/downloadZip", new HttpHandler() {

                @Override
                public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
                    if (!handleTokenPreflight(exchange)) { return; }
                    System.out.println(exchange.getRequestURI());
                    Map<String, String> queryParam = parseQueryParam(exchange.getRequestURI().getQuery());

                    String authToken = exchange.getRequestHeaders().getFirst("token");
                    String target = queryParam.get("target") + ",";
                    String[] files = new String[Integer.parseInt(queryParam.get("numberOfFiles"))];

[...] // I process the data in this entire method and send it to the previous method that creates a zip

                    Controller.getDownloadZip(files, folderName);

                    // what do I return to download the file on the client's browser ????
                    return;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach to successfully download your zip file can be the described in the following paragraphs.

First, consider returning a reference to the zip file obtained as the compression result in your `downloadZip` method:

```java
public File getDownloadZip(String[] files, String folderName) throws IOException {
  [...] // The method is huge but basically I generate a folder called "Download/" in the server

  // Zipping the "Download/" folder
  File selectedFilesZipFile = new File("selected-files.zip")
  ZipUtil.pack(new File("Download"), selectedFilesZipFile);

  // return the zipped file obtained as result of the previous operation
  return selectedFilesZipFile;
}
```

Now, modify your `HttpHandler` to perform the download:

```java
server.createContext("/files/downloadZip", new HttpHandler() {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        if (!handleTokenPreflight(exchange)) { return; }
        System.out.println(exchange.getRequestURI());
        Map<String, String> queryParam = parseQueryParam(exchange.getRequestURI().getQuery());

        String authToken = exchange.getRequestHeaders().getFirst("token");
        String target = queryParam.get("target") + ",";
        String[] files = new String[Integer.parseInt(queryParam.get("numberOfFiles"))];

    [...] // I process the data in this entire method and send it to the previous method that creates a zip

        // Get a reference to the zipped file
        File selectedFilesZipFile = Controller.getDownloadZip(files, folderName);

        // Set the appropiate Content-Type
        exchange.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/zip");

        // Optionally, if the file is downloaded in an anchor, set the appropiate content disposition
        // exchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=selected-files.zip");
        
        // Download the file. I used java.nio.Files to copy the file contents, but please, feel free
        // to use other option like java.io or the Commons-IO library, for instance
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, selectedFilesZipFile.length());
        try (OutputStream responseBody = httpExchange.getResponseBody()) {
            Files.copy(selectedFilesZipFile.toPath(), responseBody);
            responseBody.flush();
        }
    }
});
```

Now the problem is how to deal with the download in Angular.

As suggested in the previous code, if the resource is public or you have a way to manage your security token, including it as a parameter in the URL, for instance, one possible solution is to not use Angular `HttpClient` but an anchor with an `href` that points to your ever backend handler method directly.

If you need to use Angular `HttpClient`, perhaps to include your auth tokens, then you can try the approach proposed in this great [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript).

First, in your `handler`, encode to Base64 the zipped file contents to simplify the task of byte handling (in a general use case, you can typically return from your server a JSON object with the file content and metadata describing that content, like content-type, etcetera):

```java
server.createContext("/files/downloadZip", new HttpHandler() {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        if (!handleTokenPreflight(exchange)) { return; }
        System.out.println(exchange.getRequestURI());
        Map<String, String> queryParam = parseQueryParam(exchange.getRequestURI().getQuery());

        String authToken = exchange.getRequestHeaders().getFirst("token");
        String target = queryParam.get("target") + ",";
        String[] files = new String[Integer.parseInt(queryParam.get("numberOfFiles"))];

    [...] // I process the data in this entire method and send it to the previous method that creates a zip

        // Get a reference to the zipped file
        File selectedFilesZipFile = Controller.getDownloadZip(files, folderName);

        // Set the appropiate Content-Type
        exchange.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/zip");

        // Download the file
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(selectedFilesZipFile.toPath());
        byte[] base64Data = Base64.getEncoder().encode(fileContent);
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, base64Data.length);
        try (OutputStream responseBody = httpExchange.getResponseBody()) {
            // Here I am using Commons-IO IOUtils: again, please, feel free to use other alternatives for writing 
            // the base64 data to the response outputstream
            IOUtils.write(base64Data, responseBody);
            responseBody.flush();
        }
    }
});
```

After that, use the following code in you client side Angular component to perform the download:

```js
this.downloadService.httpGetDownloadZip(['target1','target2']).pipe(
  tap((b64Data) => {
    const blob = this.b64toBlob(b64Data, 'application/zip');
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(blobUrl);
  })
).subscribe()
```

As indicated in the aforementioned question, `b64toBlob` will look like this:

```js
private b64toBlob(b64Data: string, contentType = '', sliceSize = 512) {
  const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  const byteArrays = [];

  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  return blob;
}
```

Probably you will need to slightly modify the `httpGetDownloadZip` method in your service to take into account the returned base 64 data - basically, change `ServerAnswer` to `string` as the returned information type:

```js
httpGetDownloadZip(target: string[]): Observable<string> {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('target', String(target)).set('numberOfFiles', String(target.length));
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('token', this.tokenService.getStorageToken());
    const options = {
      headers,
      params,
    };
    return this.http
      .get<string>(this.BASE_URL + '/files/downloadZip', options)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<ServerAnswer>('httpGetZip')));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use HttpServletRequest  on the server...
Then get its OutputStream and write to it.

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST , params="action=downloadDocument")  
  public String downloadDocument(@RequestParam(value="documentId", required=true) String documentId,
                                HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response ) 
  {     
    try {
        String docName = null;
        String documentSavePath = getDocumentSavePath();                    

    
        PDocument doc = mainService.getDocumentById(iDocumentId);
        
        if(doc==null){
            throw new RuntimeException("document with id: " + documentId + " not found!");
        }
        
        docName = doc.getName();
        String path = documentSavePath + ContextUtils.fileSeperator() +  docName;   
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + docName + "\"");
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/word");
            
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(path);
        IOUtils.copy(stream, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
                logger.error("Error downloading document! - document not found!!!! " + fnfe.getMessage() , fnfe);           
        } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error downloading document!!! " + e.getMessage(),e);          
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I am confused... where do I put that ?

Comment: you said " I am using REST"   if you are using REST this is a rest function inside of a REST controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using responseType as arraybuffer.

Eg:

```
return this.http.get(URL_API_REST + 'download?filename=' + filename, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In My Project including both front end (angular) and back end (java).

We used the below solution ( hope it work for you ):

Angular:
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

```
let observable = this.downSvc.download(opts);
    this.handleData(observable, (data) => {
      let content = data;
      const blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      saveAs(blob, file);
    });
```

Java:

```
public void download(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
      ....
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
          "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
          try (
              OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
              InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = is.read(buf)) > -1) {
              os.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            os.flush();
    }
```